# Dapper Query with NaN values

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I have a table with a numeric column type that may contain NaN values. When running a query with Dapper I get an exception `Unknown message code: 0` if the field contains NaN values.

Example schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id Serial NOT NULL, val Numeric NOT NULL );
insert into test(val) VALUES(1.5),('Nan');
```

Here is the query that is throwing an exception

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Val { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetTest()
{
    var sql = "select * from test";
    using (var connection = Postgres.GetConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            var results = await connection.QueryAsync<MyClass>(sql);
            return results;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<MyClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception being thrown. (ex variable from catch)

`Unknown message code: 0`

And here is the stack trace.

```
   at Npgsql.PGUtil.ValidateBackendMessageCode(BackendMessageCode code) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\PGUtil.cs:line 88
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 956
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__46.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 383
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<Consume>d__64.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 703
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<Close>d__68.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 740
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Close() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 714
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 709
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryAsync>d__33`1.MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 459
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyClass.<GetTest>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\MyClass.cs:line 367
```

Comment: SQL has no `NaN` value, only NULL. What you posted is just a string that contains the characters `N`, `a` and `n`. I'm surprised this `INSERT` didn't throw an outright exception! Finally, the stack trace doesn't match the code you posted. Your code hides any exceptions and just returns an empty list

Comment: [Npgsql maps numeric to decimal](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) which can't handle double.NaN. You'd have to change the table column to `real` to allow mapping to `double`. In the stack trace the exception starts inside `Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader`

Comment: The stack trace is the contents of the ex variable in the catch statement. It's interesting to me that Numeric doesn't support NaN. It does work to insert NaN using npgsql and decimal.NaN as opposed to a string 'NaN'. Changing the db type to real did fix the problem. Add it as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: PostgreSQL numeric absolutely supports NaN - [see the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html); but the literal is NaN without the single quotes, as you've noted.

Comment: *SQL* doesn't support NaN. That's a PostgreSQL extension. In C# `NaN` is a special value for double and float, not `decimal`. Since NpgSQL maps `numeric` to `decimal` though, NaN can't be mapped

Comment: @Shay Rojansky The literal NaN does need to be enclosed in single quotes in the sql or there is an error: column "nan" does not exist.

Comment: I don't see what relevance the SQL standard has this, given it's a PostgreSQL question. You're right the code above is likely incorrect as it's trying to map a .NET double to a PG numeric, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Numeric` type in Postgres does have the ability to contain NaN.

You can insert `double.NaN` just fine.

```
await connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES(@val)", new { val = double.NaN });
```

Or like this: (note that single quotes are required around the NaN literal)

```
INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES('NaN');
```

However the problem is that Numeric type matches the decimal type in C# which does not support NaN. Apparently Dapper internally tries setting a decimal property to NaN even though the property on my class is double. This is what causes the error.

The solution is to change the data type in the database to double `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `REAL`

Alternately if changing the schema is not an option you can explicitly cast to `DOUBLE PRECISION` in the query.

```
SELECT id, val::DOUBLE PRECISION FROM test
```